# Organizing UX bookmarks folder

Tags: ordering, organization, bookmarklet

I enjoy *stumbling upon* the web for finding great and inspirational UX resources which I bookmark for future reference.

I think I have a well organized UI & Design bookmark folder tree that includes icons, fonts, images, backgrounds, textures, color schemes, etc. However, when it comes to gestures, forms, interactions, usability, I can't seem to find a way of organizing my bookmarks UX folder tree.

As a way to set a starting point, I was looking at the extense [ux.stackexchange.com tags page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags) but there are a lot of them.

What is the best way to name my subfolders in a UX bookmark tree considering relevance as a priority?

```
UX/
 - Gestures/
 - Forms/
 - Usability/
 - User-behavior/
```

You can also take a look at this [web design repo](http://www.webdesignrepo.com/) which I consider has a great topic organization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not really about user experience; it's about organisation of articles, and many opinions may appear here, with no definite answer.

Comment: Maybe htis question should be reworded as a categorization case study, e.g. something like "how do I categorize gestures, forms, interactions, usability as subcategories withing the broader topic of UX?"